# Schengen visa reservation of return flight from another country than accommodation

Tags: visas, schengen, tourist-visas

I am going for travel from Barcelona (which is my main destination) and will continue to Amsterdam. Instead of booking my return flight from Amsterdam, the travel agency booked my return flight from Barcelona.

My accommodation papers show that I was in Amsterdam 1-2 days before the return flight. After I told him that I am getting back from Amsterdam, he said it doesn't matter there is train (which makes the story that I did go from Barcelona to Amsterdam, and then from Amsterdam back to Barcelona for my return trip).

Do they actually care about this a the embassy? Can my visa get rejected because of this?

Comment: You seem to be more concerned about which story to tell in your visa application than about the fact that the travel agent has booked your flight from a different city than the one you want to return from, and apparently expects you to arrange (and pay for?) your own train travel rather than fix his error. This sounds extremely strange. Are you, in fact, NOT intending to leave the Schengen area after your (ostensible) visit?

Comment: Im planning to return from Amsterdam, but this only reservation until I get the visa, because I don't want to lose money. @HenningMakholm

Comment: I would not worry about the travel from Barcelona to Amsterdam as there are more than 12 daily flights between these cities. In fact, I wouldn't even bother booking the Barcelona - Amsterdam flight until I got the visa.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see this being any issue at all. Because of the way that airline fares work, it's very common for people who want to visit cities A and B to get a return ticket from their home to A and a separate return ticket (train, plane, whatever) from A to B. This is a normal situation and you don't need to lie about it. Lying is always a bad idea because it makes your case less convincing and your application will be rejected if they find out that you're lying.

First, sort out with your travel agent what flights you'll actually be taking. Then tell the visa people what you'll be doing.